# How to pass IVector<string> in Typescript

Tags: typescript, winjs, win-universal-app

In a Windows 10 Universal app, I'm trying to use the FileSavePicker to select a file. I am using Typescript. The insert method takes two parameters, a string and an IVector. The following code is from the MS website, but it is just straight javascript.

```
savePicker.fileTypeChoices.insert("Word Document", [".docx"]);
```

The error text is, "Argument of type string[] is not assignable to parameter of type IVector". I have been able to get it to work using this:

```
var tempVec: Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVector<string>;
tempVec.append(".docx");
savePicker.fileTypeChoices.insert("Word Document", tempVec);
```

That seems unreasonably verbose. Is there a better syntax for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

> "Argument of type string[] is not assignable to parameter of type IVector"

Seems like a bug in winjs TypeScript definitions. If the following is a valid case

```
savePicker.fileTypeChoices.insert("Word Document", [".docx"]);
```

The argument signature should be`IVector<string> || Array<string>`, OR `IVector` should be compatible with `Array` e.g. `IVector<string> implements Array<string>`.

> That seems unreasonably verbose.

Based on the definition (which like I said might be incorrect and a bug should be reported) this is the way to go.